# PHP -S service ? "php -S localhost index.php" image is not displaying on server on localhost

Tags: php, apache, service

everyone i have php simple some code :

```
project
 |- index.php
 |- banana.jpg
```

`file: index.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

  <img src="banana.jpg" alt="">

</body>
</html>
```

So, i open command prompt in `project` folder and run `$ php -S localhost:8000 index.php` then open browser

but not show my image :(

[image]

Please help and tell me about solution way...

Thank you so much

Comment: what happens when you start the server inside the folder? `$ cd ~/project`
`$ php -S localhost:8000`

Comment: yes, i run "php -S localhost:800" in project folder

Comment: open the browser's developer tools, go to the network tool and then re-load your page. Watch for a request to the jpg file, and see what error code it returns. If you don't see one, then go to the Elements section and check the img tag is actually there in the code of your page.

Comment: Does it give any error if you try to open `localhost:8000/banana.jpg` ?

Comment: @milenmk yes i tried it's blank page
this image>> https://ibb.co/Lv8q3bS

Comment: @ADyson this dev tool >>  https://ibb.co/G7ZYswS

Comment: What happened ? about my project 

My PHP version
PHP : v7.1.19

Comment: Maybe the jpg file itself is blank?? The code looks like it should work.

Answer (score 0):

It must be a bug in the php web server, I did tests with version 8.0.9 and the same thing happens to me, it does not recognize the type.

[image]

With `php -S localhost: 8000` it works correctly, by default php executes the index.php file

```
php -S localhost: 8000
```

If the file is in "public/index.php" you could run:

```
php -S localhost: 8000 -t public
```

You can find more information at :https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php